# What is wrong with this sorting code? Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

So i'm supposed to take in a number n, add n numbers to a list, then sort the list and print.

```
numCol=int(input());
vals=[];
for x in range(numCol):
    vals.append(int(input()))

for x in range(len(vals)):
    curr=vals[x];
    for y in range(x+1,len(vals)):
        if(curr>vals[y]):
            temp=vals[y];
            vals[y]=curr;
            vals[x]=temp;
print(vals);
```

the code doesn't work properly. We haven't learned sorting algorithms thoroughly really yet, so i'm kinda just making my own, but it resembles selection sort I think. Anyways, why is it not printing the values in ascending order?

Edit: I input 4, then make list 4, 3, 2, 1. Output is [1, 4, 4, 4]

Comment: provide sample input, actual output and expected output

Comment: this is only making one pass through the list ... you need to continue until you make no swaps ... also you can swap in python with `vals[x],vals[y]=vals[y],vals[x]`

Comment: Are you required to implement a sorting algorithm? Because the practical answer would be to use the built-in Python sorting method(s).

Comment: We have to make our own sorting algorithm, but it can resemble a premade algorithm. I'm basing this off of selection sort I think. How is it only making one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is `curr` should change after swap.

```
for x in range(len(vals)):
    curr=vals[x];
    for y in range(x+1,len(vals)):
        if(curr > vals[y]):
            temp = vals[y]
            vals[y] = curr
            vals[x] = temp
            curr = vals[x] # <--
```

Comment: thanks! that did it! How would I incorporate curr, butt update accordingly?

Comment: @DChalo according to your code, `curr` is the value of `vals[x]`, so whenever `vals[x]` changes, update `curr` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part of code

```
 for x in range(len(vals)):
    curr=vals[x];
    for y in range(x+1,len(vals)):
        if(curr>vals[y]):
            temp=vals[y];
            vals[y]=curr;
            vals[x]=temp;
```

To this:

```
for x in range(len(vals)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(vals)):
        if(vals[x]>vals[y]):
            temp=vals[y];
            vals[y]=vals[x];
            vals[x]=temp;
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can solve sorting of lists much easier and in a more pythonic way, simply use the sort command, here is an example:

```
import random

a=random.sample(range(30), 10)
print a
a.sort()
print a
```

Comment: Thanks! It's just for this problem we couldn't use a built in algo

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome -

```
numCol=int(input());
vals=[];
for x in range(numCol):
    vals.append(int(input()))

for x in range(len(vals)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(vals)):
    if(vals[x]>vals[y]):
        temp=vals[y]
        vals[y]=vals[x]
        vals[x]=temp
print(vals)
```

The problem was that you weren't changing the value of cur to be compared correctly.

Edit - Just saw other answers had beat me to it :(